# Fire trigger only if we update custom field

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-object, update, triggercontext

I have an object in `Salesforce` called `File_uploaded__c` with some fields like `Filename__c, fileSize__c, IsMain`, and I want to know if there's a way to implement a trigger that is only fired when we update the field `IsMain` and not every time we update the whole object

Comment: what does the trigger need to do. does it need to update some value on the child object. it is possible to do in trigger by comparing the trgger.oldmap value with the trigger.new value. Post your code till now what you tried.

Comment: in My object all the objects of `File_uploaded__c` shoud have One file as Main so when a user change another field as main the old main file shoud be set to false, but if he changes anther field like Filename or what ever the trigger shouldn't be fired

Comment: Ok when the trigger has fire only on main field changes then you had to do a if condition and check the oldMap.Main and new value of Main. you can refer the answer provided by Chris Duncombe for your question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this by comparing the current value of the IsMain field with the value in the trigger.oldMap collection.  This will tell you if the field has changed.

Something like this will work

```
trigger FileUploadedTrigger on File_uploaded__c (after update) {

     list<File_uploaded__c> changedIsMainList = new list<File_uploaded__c>();
     for(File_uploaded__c fu : trigger.new){
          if(fu.IsMain__c != trigger.oldMap.get(fu.Id).IsMain__c){
               changedIsMainList.add(fu);
          }
     }
     //You now have a list of only those File_uploaded__c records where IsMain
     //has changed.  You can now perform your logic on only those records

     //YOUR LOGIC HERE
}
```

This should get you started.  I would also recommend reading through [Apex Code Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices) as well.

Comment: it's a good answer but every time i update some fields in my object the trigger will be fired even if it's not `IsMain` field and i wanna avoid that if it's possible

Comment: You cannot  control the actual firing of the trigger itself.  You can however,  control which records within that trigger you take action on.  The triggers for an object will always be fired when a record has DML performed on it.

Comment: This is a great answer and the article Chris linked is a great read as well - just out of curiosity, why do you want to prevent the trigger from firing at all?

Comment: Well, the field : `IsMain__c` is not the only one i will be updating, and when the trigger is fired it will only modify the field `IsMain__c`

Comment: That is fine, but there is no harm in the trigger firing when the IsMain__c field is not changed.  The trigger will basically do nothing as you will only be acting on records where that field did exist.

Comment: No worries.  Glad to help